# Conditional .htaccess for URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^photographs/?$ photographs.php [L]
RewriteRule ^photographs/(.*)/?$ photographs.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^photographs/(.*)/(.*)/?$  photographs.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

I need this to have options such as

- /photographs
- /photographs/category
- /photographs/category/3

Thanks

Comment: not sure what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^photographs/?$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^photographs/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^photographs/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$  index.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

That's because `(.*)` also matches `/` character.